# Imporove voice track in video files mp4 and mkv

Tags: audio, video

Often the voices in a movie or serial will be drowned out by loud music or background noise, often this is deliberate on the part of the studio thinking it improves the drama or what ever. but for the hearing impaired who don't want to read subtitles or deafen the neighbors it makes the video unwatchable.
So is there a filter available that can be used to alter the balance so voices
have priority over all other sounds? in  any type of video container mp4 and mkv especially.

Comment: If your watching on your PC, you can turn on Loudness equalization, which will do exactly what you want. However, it does not actually change the file, just adjusts the volume levels.

Comment: Often, the effects you describe are really caused by e.g. a 5.1 audio track being played on stereo (2.0) equipment (missing the appropriate decoder), so that could be a starting point.

Comment: @ClassStacker Besides buying 5.1 equipment, what can be done?